# POST image on Dompdf

Tags: php, image, post, dompdf

I need to place in my PDF (generated through Dompdf) an image that will be received through a POST request, but the image does not appear, follow the example of the PHP code:

```
<?php
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;
    if ($_FILES['imagem']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      $imagem_tmp = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
      require('vendor/autoload.php');

      $options = new Options();
      $options->setChroot(__DIR__);
      $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

      $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

      $html = '<html>
                 <body>
                   <img src="' . $imagem_tmp . '">
                 </body>
               </html>';

      $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

      $dompdf->render();

      $nome_pdf = 'meu_pdf.pdf';
      file_put_contents($nome_pdf, $dompdf->output());
      echo 'PDF gerado com sucesso: <a href="' . $nome_pdf . '">Baixar PDF</a>';
    } else {
      echo 'Erro ao fazer upload da imagem.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide reference why this should work in the first place.

Comment: The `$imagem_tmp` variable in your code contains the [temporary filename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server. This is in no way related to any HTML output. The best way, I think, to get images in Dompdf is to [encode the image data with Base64](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html).